# Dynamically add model row to table

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've read a bunch of articles now, from Phil Haacks "model binding to a list" to Steve Sanderson's "Editing a variable length list" and now trying to solve my problem - however I couln't really get it working.

I have two models - Order and Article. An order has many articles. The order view contains an articles table.

Currently, I'm creating the first table row using EditorFor(model => model.Articles) from within my Order View Model.

It recognizes that Articles is a list and returns the right list items. So far so good.

Now I want a link that adds an article to the table row but by using an AJAX Request to the Controller, which then returns a partial view (only containing the article table row). I already got that working using this tutorial: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

However, my problem is that I don't know how i can continue the article row sequence in ASP.NET MVC "style", so that it will get recognized on submit. (e.g. Articles[1].Number Articles[2].Number etc.)

Here's my code. The "add article" link should add an article and send an ajax request to /orders/BlankArticleRow

```
public ActionResult BlankArticleRow(int pos)
        {
            Article article = new Article()
            {
                Position = pos
            };

            return View(article);
        }
```

The partial view for BlankArticleRow looks like this:

```
@model Bestellinterface.Models.Article

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Works fine. When i click the "add article" link the row gets added, however the attributes of the text fields etc. do not have the right format. What i want is that it continues the numbering of the html elements,  Articles[0].Number, Articles[1].Number, Articles[2].Number ...

Is that possible with EditorFor? Is there a way to simulate a list so that it will keep numbering?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `EditorFor` for this:

```
    @{ int i = 0; }
@foreach (var article in Model.Articles)
{
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Articles[i])
i++;
}
```

Assuming the editor template contains fields Title, Description we would end up with Articles[i].Title, Articles[i].Description.

One solution for you may be to return a partial containing all the Articles for the Order which would then ensure your indexes are correct.

Alternatively you can update the indexes of your inputs with javascript.

To keep the indexes correct when removing items from a dynamic table I wrote the following:

```
//reset index values
$('#links-table tbody tr').each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').prop('name', function (i, e) { return e.replace(/(\d+)/g, index) });
});
```

This looks for the index in each input's name e.g. Articles[2].Title and replaces it with the new index. You could potentially do something similar on the success of your ajax call.

Hope that helps
Ben

Comment: Hello Ben, where should I put that code on the top? I just ask because my OrderViewModel already contains code like this to render the Articles and it works fine - my problem is the partial view, which should only render that table row. What I'm really looking for is a parameter for EditorFor which forces EditorFor to render the inputs in "list style", but AFAIK thats not possible, so I'll probably stick with the javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the extension Steve created

If you look at the article it is used like this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts")) { %>
    Item: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %> 
    Value: $<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { size = 4 }) %> 
<% }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the extension that Steve Sanderson created isn't helpful for me, since it generates a random ID for each "row". The tutorial also says that generating a following sequence is more work (but thats what i need)

Comment: I am not sure I follow...it generates a random value, but only so MVC can keep track of the values together. If you mean the ID generation at the database level, that won't be an issue with this. I've used this technique with Identity columns....

Comment: Just to clarify...the value that is generated by the extension, isn't the same Id that you would use to save in the DB..